# Using an array of CSS selectors in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to use the jQuery autocomplete plugin. I have an array of IDs that I want to plugin to work on. So, say I have:

```
var aIds = ["1", "2"];
```

The examples I see on how to use the plugin looks like this:

```
$('#1').autocomplete
```

**Is there a way for me to use this autocomplete plugin and my array of ids?** The array of ids are coming from a web service.

Also, the autocomplete plugin exposes certain events like `select` (see: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#event-select). When that happens, how can I tell which element triggered the event (if I am assigning the array of ids dynamically)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a selector:

```
$('#' + aIds.join(', #')).autocomplete();
```

Comment: Looks great. Now, when an event is triggered, how do I know which element triggered the event?

Comment: Not sure how it works, but `$(this)` references the object that the event is called by.

Answer (score 1):

`for(i=0;i<aIds.length;i++)` 
    `$('#'+aIds[i]).autocomplete();`

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just need to join them together and pass it in. Jquery is great and lets you pass in multiple selectors.

```
   var aIds = ["1", "2"];

    // join together your IDS
    var selectors = "#" + aIds.join(",#");

    // pass in as selectors
    $(selectors).autocomplete
```